# iptables show just one chain

Tags: iptables, firewall, awk

**tldr: How can I get iptables to show just one chain?**

I can have iptables show just one table, but a table consists of multiple chains. I need to find where in chain INPUT is the last rule (usually but not always the REJECT all rule).

I've tried awk and even some grep, but my skill in those must be waning. I've tried using awk to get just one paragraph, but that doesn't seem to work on the output of `iptables --line-numbers -n -L -t filter` maybe because those blank lines aren't really blank.

I am looking for a solution with any normal gnu tools that would be installed on a CentOS 6 minimal environment.

Comment: `iptables -L INPUT -n -v -t filter`

Answer (score 40, accepted):

I almost deleted this question. D'oh! From `man iptables`:

```
   -L, --list [chain]
          List  all rules in the selected chain.
```

Comment: Fortunately, you didn't delete it :) Your self-answering question is top 1 Google search result, and gets 18k views! RTFM(✘) Google it (✔)

Answer (score 4):

For those who might want to look at the mangle or nat tables with chains you can do so like

```
iptables -L mychainname -t mangle
```

Then it will show you that chain in the mangle table.

Answer (score 0):

`-S` option too can do the job:

```
iptables -S INPUT | tail -1
```